# Self reflection questionnaire: providing three different scores for a quiz

Tags: javascript, moodle

It is the first time that I post in the forum. I followed all the tips and I looked for possible answers to my query before I post it, but I couldn't find the answer for one step I am stuck. I am not a programmer. I am an educational technologist and I work with Moodle. I have created some blocks in PHP, but this is new to me.

I have been asked to created a self-contained HTML file that can be run in Moodle that works like a multiple choice questionnaire/quiz but that provides three different kind of scores to students. The quiz is based on the 'Self-Reflection and Insight Scale Questionnaire' which has 20 questions which are similar to this:

> **Q1: I don’t think often about my thoughts**
>
> Possible answers (one choice):
>
> 1. Disagree Strongly (6 points)
> 2. Disagree (5 points)
> 3. Disagree Slightly (4 points)
> 4. Agree Slightly (3 points)
> 5. Agree (2 points)
> 6. Agree strongly (1 point)

Looking into the Internet forums, I believe that the best way of creating every question of the quiz is using this function `document.getElementById`.

The problem is how to create the function validate because the 20 questions are scored as follows (this score is generated adding the questions):

```
Score 1                     Scored 2                   Score 3
(Engagement in reflection)  (Need for self-reflection) (Insight)
--------------------------  -------------------------- ----------
1 (R)                       2 (R)                       3
8 (R)                       5                           4 (R)
10                          7                           6
13 (R)                      12                          9
16                          15                          11 (R)
19                          18                          14 (R)
                                                        17 (R)
                                                        20
```

where `R` means the negative value of the selected choice (i.e. if the selected answer is valued 6 points, then the value of the question should be added as - 6.

---

I am asking for the community advice about the following:

1) I believe that the best language for programming this is javascript and not php, can you please confirm?

2) Should I use the function `document.getElementById`, or is there any more efficient way of creating three different categories of scores to be displayed.

3) Can you please refer me to the manuals/tutorials in Internet in which I can refresh my memory of javascript (assuming that javascript is the best option). I haven't used it since 2006.

Thank you very much for your advice.
Mari Cruz

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is make something like a select box, such as:

```
<select id='question1'>
    <option value=5>Disagree strongly</option>
    <option value=4>Disagree </option>
    <option value=-3> .... </option> <!-- negative -->
    <!-- etc. etc. -->
</select>
```

To get the value, you could do that by, indeed, using javascript, and jQuery (search for some tutorials on jQuery, you won't be dissapointed, it's one of the best frameworks around.)

```
//jQuery
var answer1 = $("#question1 option:selected").val();

//normal javaScript
var s = document.getElementById('question1');
var answer1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
```

I hope this does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Moodle it would be much easier and quicker to create the quiz or questionnaire in [Hot Potatoes](https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Hot_Potatoes)  (which is free to download), since Moodle allows this format of file to be uploaded as a quiz right into a particular course or into a Question bank. The downside is that it will show total scores and not break them down by question scores.

A [proprietary XML tool](http://vletools.com/info/help) is also available which is free with facebook sign-in.

GIFT format can be used with a bulk upload tool, several have been written to upload based on an Excel file you complete. Check the moodle user forum for details. This gives a good overview of alternatives https://wiki.ucl.ac.uk/display/UCLELearning/Building+Moodle+quizzes+quickly